# Why do I get an "no suitable context info for active keying action" message when trying to keyframe a camera?

Tags: camera, keyframes

When I try to do it, it says "no suitable context info for active keying action". How do I fix this and deploy the camera to different angles in different keyframes?

Answer (score 0):

I parented the camera to an empty and then keyframed the empty. I couldn't find any other solution to the problem.